# Javascript Discord, give a mentioned user a role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I just wanted to ask how I add a command that gives a person a role. So that you can type in: "addRole @user#1234" and the user get the role.

Comment: With code, as always. Please create a [mcve], explain what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: Can you post what you attempted and list what you tried from other tutorials. Just asking a vague question here won't get answered.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't give any example codes, I'm going to show you the approach of doing so myself.

Firstly, you have to get two variables, one for the **role** you want to give, and one for the **member** you are giving.
You can get a **role** by its id (also by name but using [Collection#find](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find))
You can get a **member** from a mention in a message by the using [Message#mentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions)

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.get('roleIdBetweenQuotes');
let member = message.mentions.members.first();
// A message can have more than one mention, which results in giving us a collection of members.
// So we have to use first() to get the first member in that collection.
```

After getting both variables, you will have to add the **role** to the **member** by using the [GuildMember#addRole](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole) function.

```js
member.addRole(role)
  .then(memberAdded => { // Optional
    message.channel.send(`Added role ${role.name} to ${member.displayName}`);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

We add the role to the member. The [GuildMember#addRole](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole) function returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so in order to send a message after it, you have to wait till the promise gets resolved, then sending a confirmation message. Also, you can log an error if the promise gets rejected.

Comment: my code now looks like:     `let role = message.guild.roles.get('Stream 1');
      let member = message.mentions.members.first();
      if (msg.content === 'addRole') {

        member.addRole(role)
          .then(memberAdded => { // Optional
            message.channel.send(`Added role ${role.name} to ${member.displayName}`);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });         
      }`

Comment: `roles.get()` can only get roles by their id, if you want to get it by name, you would do this:  
`message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Stream 1');`